# заменить запятую на точку в параметре float перед валидацией Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Существует базовая модель и модели, значения которых приходят из формы как вложенные параметры. Необходимо заменить запятую на точку в приходящем параметре типа `float`, чтобы можно было вводить в форму как 23.5, так и 23,5. Но Rails обрезает значения после запятой. Пытаюсь сделать такую проверку в модели, используя коллбэки `before_save`, `before_validation` вот так:

```
before_validation(on: :create) do
  self.total_area = total_area.to_s.gsub(',', '.').to_f if attribute_present?("total_area")
end
```

Но сюда значения приходят уже обрезанные, только с целой частью. Как можно решить данную проблему, не вынося исполнение кода в контроллер?

Comment: Как только вы перешли на уровень модели AR, вы уже потеряли исходные строки. И преобразовав число обратно в строку, вы уже не увидите исходной запятой. Кстати, приложите определение таблицы.